# Repair an Access database from the command line

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-access

I just solved an issue after about a week of headaches: I had an Access 97 database which I could not open with anything (Access 2007, Excel 16 importing, etc). It would say "The operation is invalid without a current index" or "The current user account doesn't have permission to convert or enable this database." I would find out using a recovery program that this database did not have any set users in its security, which is bizarre.

I solved the problem from a [2003 post in this thread](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20278216/Operation-invalid-without-a-current-index.html). I opened Excel 16, opened the Data tab, selected "From Other Sources", selected "From Microsoft Query", chose "New Data Source", supplied a name of my choosing, chose Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb), and hit the "Connect" button.

A dialog opens where you can choose the MDB file. It also has another button, "Repair". If I hit "Repair" when selecting my problematic database, it then will work with any application without throwing either of the errors I was getting.

What I want to know is how to use this "Repair" function from the command line, if possible. I will need to include operations on this database as part of a batch file with 40 other databases that were not giving me any errors.

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean Repair permissions?

Comment: [Here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Access) are the command-line switches for MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

**You may try these VBA code lines to repair Database in different situations.**

*Syntax to Auto-Repair:*

`acCompactRepair "C:\Folder\Database.accdb", True`

*You may try this also:*

- Launch Access,
- Open the database,
- Sets the **Compact On Close** option to **"True**",
- Finish with Quit.

  *If you want to Repair Database,not the one you are working with:*

`Application.compactRepair sourecFile, destinationFile`

*If you want to Repair the Database you are working with:*

`Application.SetOption "Auto compact", True`

**Edited:**

*This Command can be used to compact Aceess database at command line or through a Batch File.*

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSAccess.exe" "C:\MyDatabase.mdb" /compact "C:\Backup.mdb"
```

*Or this can be used also as set scheduled task.*

- Go to **Control Panel** then scheduled tasks to open the DB.

Set option **Compact on Close.**

*Through Batch file:*

```
@echo off
taskkill /im MSACCESS.EXE /f
```

- Save & Rename the file to *.bat
- Schedule the batch file to Run.

**Note,** I would like to recommend, don't try to compact without a target database.

Comment: Thank you! I'm specifically trying to include the repair in a batch file - could I use this VBA code by running Access from the command line with the /X flag? The use case is that I will need to copy a future backup of this DB that doesn't have any macros saved to it, so I'd like to know if this is possible to automate with a fresh copy.

Comment: @pidgezero,, yes it;s possible to compact/repair Database as well as Backup using batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for - the `/compact` flag for msaccess.exe does exactly this.

`msaccess.exe /compact "c:\path\to\my\database.mdb"`